# PyQt4 - Widget Is Not Shown

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qwidget

I've made this program in Python and Qt4.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import QtCore


color = QtGui.QColor(99, 0, 0)

class colorButton(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, args):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self,args)
        self.setGeometry(150, 22, 50, 50)
        self.setStyleSheet("QWidget { background-color: %s }" % color.name())

class ColorDialog(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):

        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self.setGeometry(40, 40, 220, 100)
        self.setWindowTitle('ColorDialog')

        button=colorButton(self)


app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
cd = ColorDialog()
cd.show()
app.exec_()
```

The intrpreter doesn't give me any error, but the "colored" widget isn't shown. Why?
thank

Comment: class colorButton(QtGui.QWidget) is missing a ':', but that would yield a SyntaxError ...

Comment: In Python, class names usually start with a capital letter.

Answer (score 4):

Your class `colorButton` inherits from `QWidget`, yet you are calling `QPushButton.__init__()` in the constructor. Maybe you want it to inherit from `QPushButton`?

By using the following class definition, your code works for me:

```
class colorButton(QtGui.QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        QtGui.QPushButton.__init__(self, *args)
        self.setGeometry(150, 22, 50, 50)
        self.setStyleSheet("QWidget { background-color: %s }" % color.name())
```

Comment: I've corrected having in both case the object QtGui.Qwidget ,but noway! it still doesn't appear

Comment: I don't know what you are doing, but when I run your code after replacing the `colorButton` definition, I see the brown button.

Comment: Well, it works, but I don't want a QPushButton. Intentionally I'm using the QWidget oject.

Comment: You should probably use `super(colorButton, self).__init__(self, *args)`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to give the widget a paintEvent.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import QtCore


color = QtGui.QColor(99, 0, 0)

class colorButton(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, args):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self,args)
        self.setGeometry(150, 22, 50, 50)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        painter.fillRect(event.rect(), color)

class ColorDialog(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):

        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self.setGeometry(40, 40, 220, 100)
        self.setWindowTitle('ColorDialog')

        button=colorButton(self)


app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
cd = ColorDialog()
cd.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting autoFillBackground to True  before you change the color (before setStylesheet call). AND I think you need to set the pallete. This comment assumes that you meant "the color of the widget is not shown". Please review the syntax as the one illustrated below is for Qt4.3 and I didn't check the latest one. After you set the pallet, there is no need to set the stylesheet.

```
class colorButton(QtGui.QWidget)
    def __init__(self, args):
        QtGui.QPushButton.__init__(self,args)
        self.setGeometry(150, 22, 50, 50)


    self.setAutoFillBackground(True)
    plt = QtGui.QPalette()      
    plt.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Active,QtGui.QPalette.Window,color)
    plt.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive,QtGui.QPalette.Window,color)  
    plt.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled,QtGui.QPalette.Window,color
    self.setPalette(plt) 


    #self.setStyleSheet("QWidget { background-color: %s }" % color.name())
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to give your ColorDialog a Layout using

```
self.setLayout(SOME_LAYOUT)
```

then add your button to the layout with something like

```
self.layout().addItem(button)
```

Otherwise I am not sure if simply giving your button the ColorDialog as parent is sufficient for display.